# WebpackError: ReferenceError: window is not defined - npm run build

Tags: javascript, gatsby

I get the following error when i do "npm run build" :

WebpackError: ReferenceError: window is not defined

this is a part of code that causes an error:

```
    params.slidesPerView =  Math.floor(window.innerWidth/400);
    // params.slidesPerGroup = Math.floor(window.innerWidth/400);
    console.log("Calc Width");
    console.log(window.innerWidth/400);
    this.lastWidth = params.slidesPerView;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

During your development, you can access to window in client. When you run build, gatsby renders these components on the server where window is not defined.

Solution is the use window in `componentDidMount` or check window before you want use it.

Comment: "componentDidMount"  How to use it ?

Comment: See this link: https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/debugging-html-builds/#how-to-check-if-code-classlanguage-textwindowcode-is-defined

Comment: Read number 1 in above link in gatsby documention.